# Android BroadcastReceiver to get all SDCARD Status

Tags: android

I'm trying to get all SD card statuses using the BroadcastReceiver, but the code isn't working correctly. The BroadcastReceiver does not give a comprehensive log after a change in SD card status, such as Turn on(off) USB Storage. Any ideas?

Manifest receiver actions:

```
<receiver android:name=".Broadcasts.BroadcastChangeSDCardStatus">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

OR this receiver defined:

```
<receiver android:name=".Broadcasts.BroadcastChangeSDCardStatus">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver class to detect

```
public class BroadcastChangeSDCardStatus extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean status = getStorageStatus();
        Log.e("SDCARD Status: ", status + "");
    }
    public static boolean getStorageStatus() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm after adding this permission resolve my problem now:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name=".Broadcasts.BroadcastChangeSDCardStatus" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Above code should work but as you said you already tried this so it looks like something is wrong with your receiver name .Your broadcast receivers is not registered.Give receiver name complete package name with class name  correctly

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the `android:scheme` to "file" : 
Do this by adding `<data android:scheme="file" />` to your receiver like:

```
<receiver android:name=".Broadcasts.BroadcastChangeSDCardStatus">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
        <data android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Hope this helps you out